# Having three plots with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to have three plots. the first one one the top of the two other. I can produce the two bottom plots, but can't produce the big first on the top:

[image]

here is my code to produce this diagram:

```
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout=grid.layout(3,2)))

vplayout <- function(x,y)
  viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)

psig <- function(x, y, z){
  h <- data.frame(index = c(1:length(subsignals[[x]])),
                  orders = subsignals[[x]])
  lab <- paste("Subseries ", as.character(x), sep="")
  print(qplot(index, orders, data = h, geom = "line", main=lab), vp = vplayout(y,z))
  TRUE
}

psig(1,3,1); psig(2,3,2);
```

I have the parameter `datalist`

```
datalis<-c(#some data)
```

and I want to plot datalist on the top of these two plots.(it is possible that I have more than two plots at the bottom, but I want two have `datalist` plot at the top of another plots

How can I do that?

Comment: I find tasks like this easier with nesting `arrangeGrob` inside `grid.arrange` (both from the gridExtra package).

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `arrangeGrob` you can do this :

```
library(gridExtra)
print(arrangeGrob(p1,arrangeGrob(p2 , p3,nrow=1), nrow=2,heights=c(3, 1)))
```

For example:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
p0 <- ggplot(cars)+geom_line(aes(speed,dist))

print(arrangeGrob(p0,arrangeGrob(p0 , p0,nrow=1), nrow=2,
             heights=c(3, 1)))
```

[image]